# Angular APP_INITIALIZER with useClass

Tags: angular, typescript

I need some API data before application startup and am doing it currently with APP_INITIALIZER and useFactory. Now I want to separate all the code from app.module.ts for better structure:

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { httpInterceptorProvider, appInitProvider } from '@core';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        httpInterceptorProvider,
        appInitProvider
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

@core/init/index.ts

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { InitService } from './init.service';

export const appInitProvider = [
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useClass: InitService, multi: true }  
];
```

@core/init/init.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { SettingsService } from "@core";

@Injectable()
export class InitService implements Resolve<any> {
  
    constructor(
        private _http: HttpClient,
        private settings: SettingsService,
    ) {}

    resolve() {
        const promise = this._http.get("/API")
        .toPromise()
        .then((data: any) => {
            this.settings.setSettings(data);
            return data;
        });
        return promise;
    }

}
```

When doing this I get the angular error

> TypeError: this.appInits[i] is not a function at
> ApplicationInitStatus.runInitializers

I have the same setup for the http interceptor and there it is working without any problems.

---

**EDIT:** accepted answer is the correct way to go also I needed to tweak the given code a little bit to make it work. Here is the final index.ts:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { InitService } from './init.service';

export const appInitProvider = [
    InitService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (service:InitService)=>{return () => service.resolve()}, deps: [InitService], multi: true }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using useClass you should use useFactory

**Try this:**

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { InitService } from './init.service';
export const appInitProvider = [
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (service:InitService)=>{return InitService.resolve()}, deps: [InitService], multi: true }  
];
```

Comment: this was a hint in the right direction - thank you! Can you edit your answer as following with the working code? "useFactory: (service:InitService)=>{return () => service.resolve()}"

Comment: Check this:https://tutorialsforangular.com/2019/12/05/using-the-app_initializer-token-to-bootstrap-your-application/